# jQuery Ajax success function data is null?

Tags: php, ajax, null

I am novice to `ajax/php` and learning it. I am trying to pass php values through `ajax` which is successful however I am not able to get response variable from the php file to `ajax`. Although `ajax` is successful, why the data or result or response from php is `NULL`. Is there anything missing here, which I am not able to understand. Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#regform').submit(function(){
     var form = $(this),
     formData = form.serialize(),
     formUrl = form.attr('action'),
     formMethod = form.attr('method'), 

     $.ajax({
         url: formUrl,
         type: formMethod,
         data: formData,
         success:function(result){
                console.log(result)    =====> why its is NULL? 
                console.log(result.status);   ======>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 

       }
  });

});  })
```

HTML5 file as:

```
<form id="regform" method="post" action="process.php">
<fieldset>
<label for="firstName">First Name<span style="color:red;">&#42;</span></label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
<label for="Company">Company</label>
<input type="text" id="Company" placeholder="" name="Company">
<label for="telephone">Phone Number</label>
<input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone">
<label for="email">Email<span style="color:red;">&#42;</span></label>
<input type="email" id="email" pattern="([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required>
<input name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Register" type="submit"> 
</fieldset>
    </form>
```

And php file :**process.php**

```
         $status="Success!!!";
         $message="You are welcome";

         $data = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message
        );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
                    exit;
```

Any help, directions, insight on the problem/solution would be much more appreciated. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You have to put `exit;` after echo json_encode($data);

Answer (score 0):

Add Following code,

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: "process.php",
    data: 'name='+name,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result) 
        console.log(result.status);    
    }
});
```

Remove `jQuery.parseJSON()`...There is no need to parse when you use `json_encode()`...

Comment: Hey Akshay and Gowri, I've updated the code above and removed jQuery.parseJSON() and added exit; on the php file at the end.However console.log(result) is still NULL so as result.status. :(. My question is why NULL? How to debug?

Comment: I also have tested in my local, and its working fine...
Check here `http://prntscr.com/2nwipj`...

Comment: Hey Akshay, I have updated the actual code now . but it is giving me the same NULL. What I am trying to do here is I am submitting the HTML5 form with HTML5 validation, through ajax to php and return the success! message from the PHP which is similar to one you have solved. However, here I am not able to do so could you give some insight on it Please!

Comment: I think you need to use `method="get"`...try that may be help you.